# Need Salesforce sdk.jar file

Tags: mobilesdk

I am developing a native android mobile app interfacing with salesforce. Can any one point me to where salesforcesdk.jar file is. I see it in the documentation but cant find it.
    I am aware of the github site with the source code and code templates. However I need the jar file

Answer (score 4):

The Android SDK is now an [Android Library project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html), and as such can't be just included as a jar, it needs to be included as an actual source code project. You'll want to clone the [repo](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android) and add the relevant projects to your workspace (assuming you're using eclipse)

Comment: Thanks Superfell. i have tried to clone the template project and compile it. I faced a lot of issues. I was finally able to get it to compile , but it gives an exception when i try to invoke. I will give that another try and figure it out.